# Applescript output reading problem when embedded within python

Tags: python, applescript

I am trying to make a python application that works with iTunes on MacOS and changes based on if the player is currently playing or not. I have an AppleScript passing through a boolean of if it is playing or not, but when I attempt to read it using python, it is not working with python. Same as with strings.

I tried changing to use strings instead and that doesn't work either.

```
def Update(self):
        osascript.run(self.applescript, background=True)
        self.proc = Popen(['osascript', '-'], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
        self.appscripPlayingOutput, error = self.proc.communicate(self.applescriptIsPlaying)
        print(self.appscripPlayingOutput)
        self.boolisPlay = self.str2bool(self.appscripPlayingOutput)
        print(self.boolisPlay)
        if self.boolisPlay == False:
            self.playing = False
            print("is paused")
        else:
            self.playing = True
            print("is playing")
        self.musicImage = Image.open(self.pathToAlbumArt)
        self.musicImage = self.musicImage.resize((300,300), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        self.realMusicImage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.musicImage)
        self.musicCanvas.itemconfigure(self.AlbumArtId, image=self.realMusicImage)
        root.after(1000, self.Update)
```

I want it to make playing true if it is playing and false if paused, but it consistently returns true

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by instead making the applescirpt return 1 for true and 0 for false, and then converted that into an int using python